# Getting Hamburger Menu to Display Navigation Links in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

At my school, we have this course on HTML5 and CSS3, and one of the sections was focused on making mobile-friendly websites. One of the things it included was a pre-made script which would show a bunch of navigation links once you click on the hamburger menu image. Here's the script here:

```
/* 
  Lakeland Reeds Bed and Breakfast menu toggle script 
  Filename: script.js
  HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lessons
*/

var navButton = document.querySelector(".navigation-menu-button img");
if (navButton.addEventListener) {
  navButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
     var nav = document.querySelector(".sitenavigation ul");
     if (nav.style.display === "block") {
        nav.style.display = "";
     } else {
        nav.style.display = "block";
     }
  }, false);
}
```

I've been fiddling with this script, and trying to mold it into exactly what my own site needs. Just so you know, .sitenavigation refers to the  html element on the page. Our website doesn't have an unordered list, so it's already different from how the above script was setup for their own pages. Here's my script for my website:

```
var navButton = document.querySelector(".img");

function showNav() {
    var navBar = document.querySelector(".nav");
    if (navBar.style.display === "block") {
        navBar.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        navBar.style.display = "block";
    }
}

showNav();
```

.img refers to the hamburger menu image, and .nav refers to the  html element. I would be using an event listener, however there is an error somewhere with the function. Chrome points to line 5, and it says, "Cannot read property 'style' of Null at showNav".

Am I making some simple mistake, and if so, then what is the fix?
If there's a much easier way, then I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot read property 'style' of Null at showNav" means that the element was not found at all.

Are you loading your Javascript via script tags? If your script tag is before your .nav element, when it loads the element won't exist yet on the page, so it will have no 'style' property.

If that's the case, you should either move your  tag to the end of the document, before the closing body tag or wait for the document to load before calling your code. You can use something like this to wait for the document to load beforehand:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //your javascript code goes here
});
```

Comment: That got rid of the error, but the script still isn't working. I changed the nav element so it has an unordered list, and it messed up the hamburger menu image, so I did away with it for now. Instead of assigning navButton to #hamburger, it's assigned to nav, the html element. Nothing pops up when I cilck on the square

Comment: You should show the HTML markup in order for us to see. There's no way to help without knowing what you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above certainly helped, but the real problem was not just that.

The script had a few logic errors in it, and the css file was the biggest problem. I had everything hidden, .nav ul, .nav li, and .nav p. Since p is a child of ul, all I needed to do was have ul hidden, and unhide it using the original script (renamed some of the elements selected in it). From there, it was just a bunch of style rules to try to get the unordered list how I wanted it to look. There's a problem with the hamburger menu image file, but I don't know how to fix that.

```
var navButton = document.querySelector("nav");
if (navButton.addEventListener) {
  navButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
     var nav = document.querySelector(".nav ul");
     if (nav.style.display === "block") {
        nav.style.display = "";
     } else {
        nav.style.display = "block";
     }
  }, false);
}
```

This is the working script. I placed the script html element above the closing body tag, and so all the elements named in the script are recognized. For some reason, the nav element is set to "block" by default, even though in the css file it is set to "none", so it is given a null value for the display rule - so it doesn't display. The else block is what happens when the nav element is clicked. .nav p elements are set to display: block; while .nav ul elements are set to display: none; in css. .nav ul element rules come after .nav p element rules. Hope this can clear it up for anyone else having this issue.